# Why am I getting cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::asio::detail::noncopyable'?

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2012, boost-asio

I am following [This](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/server.cpp) tutorial for boost SSL.  The only thing I did that was not done on that tutorial is put each class into its own files.  I have no clue where this is being thrown so its a hard one for me to debug.

**error C2248: 'boost::asio::detail::noncopyable::noncopyable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::asio::detail::noncopyable'**

Comment: The error says it all. You are prevented from copying that specific Boost.Asio object.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to store `io_service` by reference instead of by value? Impossible to tell without looking at your code

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: @avakar it doesn't point to any of my code.  It points to io_service.hpp in boost

Comment: @nijansen you were right post that as an answer and ill check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common error when working with Boost.Asio is that `boost::asio::io_service` is non-copyable, so you may only store references to it in your classes:

```
struct foo
{
    foo(boost::asio::io_service & io_service)
        : io_service_(io_service)
    {}

    private:
        boost::asio::io_service & io_service_;    // ok
};
```

If you declared `boost::asio::io_service io_service_` instead, you get the error stated above, because the initialization `io_service_(io_service)` depends on the copy constructor being called.